# Clock Class - Adjust hour in respect to timezone, with no pre defined classes

Tags: java, timezone

For my assignment i have to create a clock class. One feature is to be able to change the timezone,
which i can with a setter method. I am having trouble with the logic i guess. There are 24 timezones and then Greenwich Mean Time. So im storing timezone as an integer, -5, 12 , 0 etc. My question is how would you change the hour accordingly based on the new timezone given.

Would it involve if logic...

I'm programming in Java

So your timezone can be positive or negative.
There is current and new timezone.
Adjust hour correctly.
One more thing, this is not using the standard java classes. I've used them before, just wondering the logic.

Comment: Is the information that there are 24 time zones a feature of the assignment?  Because there's a *lot* more than 24 real world time zones, and they don't all correspond to exact one-hour offsets.

Comment: There aren't 24 timezones plus GMT.  There are 40 time zones.  GMT is one of them.

Comment: Always store the time as GMT. When you go to _display_ the time, then you can take the time zone into account.

Comment: @user2904563 [Start Here](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info)

Comment: @nhgrif There were [548 zones as of 2012c](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) and I believe several have been added since then.

Comment: Thanks for that article Matt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have the users select their specific time zone; but ideally you'd want them to select their regional time zone.  For example, people living on the eastern coast of the USA might say that their time zone right now is Eastern Standard Time, when the vast majority of them are actually using Eastern Daylight Time.

As for adjusting the hour based on their region, I would think it would be as simple as recalling their time zone from however you're storing them, checking if its daylight savings time there or not, and then producing the formatted date that is converted from Greenwich Mean Time into the time zone of the user.

So once you have the time zone offset for a particular person, then you can do the displayTime = UTCtime + timezoneOffset